# Pandas: Group values of multiple columns according to categories in a different column. And calculate avg based on the grouping for that category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set something like this.

```
Country  Continent    1970   ....   2000 .... 2011
abc        Asia        0.8   ....    0.9 .... 1.1
def        Europe      0.9   ....    1.6 .... 0.6
asd        Oceania     1.2   ....    2.3 .... 1.5
.            .
.            .          .             .         .
.            .          .             .         .
```

What I am trying to achieve is group data of years 2000 and above (only certain columns) based on the continent column. So group the data for Asia from 2000-2011, and same for Europe and so forth and then calculate avg of that grouping. My expected output is something like this.

```
Avg of Asia from 2000-2011 is: val
Avg of Europe from 2000-2011 is: val
Avg of North America from 2000-2011 is: val
```

I am fairly new to python and pandas. This is what I have tried so far. Which gives me mean of values for those years. How can do it by grouping the yearly values according to continent.

```
data_set = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
data_columns_needed = data_set[['2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011']]
mean = data_columns_needed.mean()
print(mean)
```

I am aware of the groupby method but I am not there yet to figure out how to implement it to achieve the solution to this. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: you need mean over all values from range 2000-2011 for each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
# don't forget to add the 'Country' AND 'Continent' key here:
data_columns_needed = data_set[['Country', 'Continent', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011']]

# average over a row:
data_columns_needed['row_mean'] = data_columns_needed[['2000', '2001' ... ]].mean(axis=1)

# average over a group, grouped by continents and countries:
data_columns_needed.groupby(['Continent', 'Country']).mean()
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it give me an error.
KeyError: 'Continent' . but I have a column named continent in my dataset.

Comment: Please share what error are you getting so we can help you fix it

Comment: Is it possible your headers are in the first row of your dataframe and therefore are not column names? You can print out the column names (keys) like so: `print(data.columns)`

Comment: the error trace is too long for the comment box. is there another way to share the error?

Comment: The last line should do. It should say something like `ValueError:` or `KeyError`

Comment: KeyError: 'Continent'. And this is what i get when i print the columns in my dataframe.
ndex(['Estimated HIV Prevalence% - (Ages 15-49)', 'Continent', '1979', '1980',
       '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989',
       '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998',
       '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007',
       '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: My apologies - that is because you dropped the 'Continent' column from your dataframe when you create the `data_columns_needed` variable. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the updated answer. Is there anyway I could also find a country or region in each continent that has the highest or lowest average, say from 2001 to 2011? groupby takes only one column argument and I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Yes you can, you can group by multiple columns - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your dataframe, you actually don't need a groupby. All you need is the `mean()` formula and pass the parameter `axis=0`.

Try with the following:

```
data_columns_needed['Mean'] = data_columns_needed.mean(axis=0)
new_data = pd.concat([data_set[['Country','Continent']],data_columns_needed[['Mean']]],ignore_index=True,axis=1)
new_data = new_data.groupby('Continent')['Mean'].mean()
```

Comment: I did not understand this. data_columns_needed['Mean']. I do not have a column name 'Mean'. Would the above code group the data by the continents column first and then calculate the mean of the grouping? Sorry, if i i'm being more confusing here.

Comment: The first line creates an extra column with the mean per country for the years 2000-2011. The second line adds this mean to a simple dataframe that contains Country and Continent, the third line groups by each continent all the countries and computes the mean.